# Удаление статей из базы

Tags: php

Ребят здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста 1 вопрос есть пара статей в базе, **Мне нужно при заходе на роут получить объект статьи по id и после этого удалить статью. Если статьи с таким id нет, то выдавать соответствующее сообщение. Если же статья была, то вывести объект с помощью var_dump после удаления**.

Роут добавил,Метод в абстрактном классе (получение id статьи добавил), в контролере метод написал, Но работает совсем не так как нужно, он удаляет статьи если в методе контроллера указывать id напрямую 
так

```
public function delete(): void
 {
     $article = Article::getById(7);
     if ($article == $id) {
         echo 'Статья удалена';
     } $article->delete();
      var_dump($article);
 }
```

но мне нужно что-бы статьи удалялись в зависимости от того **какой id вводишь в адресной строке**
сейчас пишу так, то есть если такой id есть удалять статью если нет выводить сообщение о том что такой статьи нет в базе
Но так он не хочет работать и **статью не удаляет из базы** не совсем понимаю что делать дальше так как только учусь

```
public function delete($id): void
     {
         $article = Article::getById($id);
         if ($article == $id) {
             echo 'Статья удалена';
         } $article->delete();
          var_dump($article);
     }
```

полностью код из всех файлов

файл ArticleController.php
https://sharecodesnippet.com/163

файл routes.php
https://sharecodesnippet.com/164

файл ActiveRecordEntity.php
https://sharecodesnippet.com/165

Comment: после $article->delete() экземпляр данного перестает существовать. делайте сначала vad_dump(), а потом уже delete, ну или запишите его куда-нибудь. кстати, вам нужна другая проверка. нужна проверка if ($article) { $article->delete(); echo "deleted"; }

Comment: Не не)) это я понял))  я иммел ввиду что после ввода вот такого адреса 
http://localhost/www/articles/delete/7 запись в базе данных не удаляеться
возможно я не совсем понимаю как это работает, мне кажеться что нужно что то добавить в метод delete вроде $this->id только я не совсем понимаю как

Comment: вы используете фреймворк yii2?

Comment: Нет пишу с нуля) все сам на основе MVC

Comment: Ну значит напишите теперь парсинг данных из урла. Хотя судя по роутам он у вас есть. Странно, что вы пишите все сами, но не знаете как прописать урл.

Comment: Не я имею ввиду что пишу сам не используя фреймворк, а так пишу по урокам, это вроде домашнего задания половину написал а дальше не пойму что делать

Answer (score 1):

Вот у вас в роутах реализуется просмотр:

```
'~^articles/(\d+)$~' => [\MyProject\Controllers\ArticlesController::class, 'view'],
```

Что здесь указано? Здесь указано что некий урл вида `articles/(\d+)` связан с методом `view` контроллера. Знаете, что такое `(\d+)`? Это **регулярное выражение**. Не вдаваясь в подробности регулярок и как реализована передача параметра в контроллер, работает это так: по шаблону регулярки `(\d+)` из урла выцепляется ИД и передается как аргумент в метод `view(int $articleId)`.

Следовательно, вам нужно сделать что? Нарисовать схожий шаблон урла в роутах:

```
'~^articles/delete/(\d+)$~' => [\MyProject\Controllers\ArticlesController::class, 'delete'],
```

И объявить метод `delete` как:

```
public function delete(int $id): void
{
    var_dump($id);
    // дальше делайте что хотите
}
```

Comment: Хм... мой косяк, у меня было подозрение что, что то с роутами не то,спасибо за подсказку пойду подтягивать регулярки

Comment: у меня вопрос по поводу void если можно)) какой его практический смысл? я так понял, что он указывает, что функция не может вернуть значение... Но если мы и не возвращаем ничего, какова ее ценность?

Comment: Объявление типа возвращаемого значения, во-первых, позволяет __без изучения__ кода функции понять, что из функции возвращается. А во-вторых, если кто-то попытается данную функцию изменить и вернуть в ней что-то, то без исправления `void` на соответствующее значение, скрипт вызывающий данный метод, упадет с эксепшеном, позволив вам отследить что и где изменилось. И дать изменившему по ушам)